# In which folder placed site on linux hosting?

Tags: linux, ssh, hosting, root

Given root ssh access to linux hosting.

I accustomed to access only site folders /www and other. And there I saw /usr /bin /var and many other folders and it scared me out.

In which folder should I search the site? I launched search over all directories but it is too slow...
I will be appreciate for any help!

Comment: Here it is! Thank you a lot, you totally helped me out. Arrange it as an answer please

Comment: Happy to help. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the web servers I've worked with have their files in `/var/www.`